# how to hide the past dates in alertdialog.builder datepicker

Tags: android

I have two fields to select fromdate and todate.The todate datepicker dialog has to restrict the past dates and show only +7 days after fromdate which was selected. The fromdate dialog has to show only 7 previous dates of current date and has to hide others.

Comment: See [setMinDate and setMaxDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these lines of code

```
d.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
d.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 + 86400000*day);
```

where `d` is datePicker dialog

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy option to control this and also to control the whole calendar options, just use the [TimeSquare](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) library which will handle the creation of your calendar in addition to how to set min and max dates, just import it and create `CalendarPickerView` object, then set it's min and max like the following:

```
Calendar firstYear = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar lastYear = Calendar.getInstance();
firstYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 0); // this will close all the past days
lastYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 20); // this will make your calendar length is 20 years

CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
calendar.init(firstYear.getTime(), lastYear.getTime())
                .withSelectedDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```